# How to loop socket program in C

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to create a basic client/server system in C for a project.  I have the basis of the idea down...I have a while loop in my client executing infinitely until the server sends the kill signal for now.  I am reading/writing blocks.  I managed to get the first read/write to work with the server, but then it's not working afterwards.

I am fairly sure I am doing something wrong with the sockets.  The idea is I want the server to wait until the client sends another write() command.  Here is what I have on the server/client:

Client

```
short connected = 1;
    do
    {
            // Send initial request on first pass
            // Afterwards send the resposne we were given
            n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
            if (n < 0)
                     error("Failed to send messege. Terminating.");
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            // Any errors?
            if (strcmp(buffer, "Session key does not match. Terminating.") == 0)
                    error(buffer);

            // Get session key response
            bzero(buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
            n = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
            if (n < 0)
                    error("Could not fetch result. Terminating.");

            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            sleep(1);
    } while (connected == 1);
```

Server

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0)
{
        printf("Error opening socket.\n");
        exit(0);
}

// Taken from reference
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
portNumber = atoi(argv[1]);
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
        printf("ERROR on binding.\n");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(0);
}

// Add listner to socket and wait until we are given something to do
// Taken from reference
listen(sockfd, 5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
if (newsockfd < 0)
{
        printf("ERROR on accept.\n");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(0);
}

// Get initial session key request
bzero(buffer,BUFFER_LENGTH);
n = read(newsockfd, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
if (n < 0)
{
        printf("ERROR reading from socket.\n");
        close(newsockfd);
        close(sockfd);
        exit(0);
}

// ... a bunch of processing of data

n = write(newsockfd, response, lengthOfKey + 15 + 1);
if (n < 0)
{
        printf("ERROR writing to socket.\n");
        close(newsockfd);
        close(sockfd);
        exit(0);
}

close(newsockfd);

// Get the previous key(s) now (we hope)
short connected = 1;
while (connected < 100)
{
        printf("waiting...\n");
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

        //... more processing
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "more processing" is at the bottom, but it needs to be the same as it is above. If you want to do the same stuff over you should just put it all in the loop to begin with.

Comment: the first read() and the second read() are not the same, but it never seems to continue after the second accept() (aka b4 the more processing)

Comment: Probably doesn't continue since you don't reconnect in the client. but why close the connection if you are going to continue the communication?

Comment: For every accept() to work in that loop, there better be a connect() coming from the client. I see exactly *none* in the client's loop. methinks Kansas has gone bye-bye.

Comment: So will the server wait on the read() block until the client sends something?  Or will the server code not hault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I found out that the read() block will stop the server code until it is given something from the client via write().  All working :)  Thanks